# On Flutter go_router how to change only content of special container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I have a page in Flutter which has 3 different elements header, sidebar and main_content. Sidebar contains some text buttons login, customer, manager etc.

When someone clicks on the button on the sidebar i want to change only the content of the main_content. I dont want to replace whole screen. I just want to replace the content of main_content with another widget.

I am not sure if it can be done using flutter package go_router. Or I have to use state management for this case.

I tried Go_router shell routes. But i think it is made for different purpose.

[image]

Comment: You can do that with ShellRoute. See some examples [here](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/go_router/example/lib).

Comment: Do you want your route (path) to change when the color changes, or just the UI of that screen? Do you want it to be persistent, i.e. when navigating to another route and then back to still have the same color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

router config :

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _shellNavigatorKey =
GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell');

const String pageOne = '/pageone';
const String pageTwo = '/pagetwo';

final appRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: pageOne,
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
        return MainPage(child: child);
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: pageOne,
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              const MainContent(lable: 'one'),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: pageTwo,
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              const MainContent(lable: 'two'),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
);
```

main page class :

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  //child is the content of each page
  final Widget child;
  const MainPage({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          //SideBar
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => context.go(pageOne),
                      child: const Text('page One')),
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => context.go(pageTwo),
                      child: const Text('page Two')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  //Header
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: const Text('Header'),
                  ),
                  //main_MainContent
                  Expanded(child: child),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main content class :

```
    class MainContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final String lable;
  const MainContent({super.key, required this.lable});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(lable),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

run app :

```
    void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: appRouter,
    );
  }
}
```

resault :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with shellRoutes in go_router. But if you just want to change the content of the page, then you can follow this approach:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  int _selection = 0;

  List<Widget> content = [
    Container(height: double.infinity, color: Colors.grey),
    Container(height: double.infinity, color: Colors.green),
    Container(height: double.infinity, color: Colors.orange),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: content.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selection = index;
                });
              },
              title: Text("Option ${index + 1}"),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: content[_selection],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Can you give me an example using shell routes please?

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of using shellroute is for solving youre problem
use it in youre project
[image]

[image]

just like my example here
i just change the content when switching between sidebar item

Comment: Can you provide a code example please?

Comment: I post another answer for you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Following my suggestion, you would initialize a variable named `_currentMainContent` with a type of `Widget`, setting it initially to a `Placeholder` widget. This variable would represent the main content area of your application.

Whenever a user interacts with a side menu item, you would update the `_currentMainContent` variable to display the appropriate widget corresponding to the selected menu item. This approach allows for dynamic content switching within the main content area of your application.